# Why is collectd package not available in Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, 22.04

collectd was available in 20.04 but when trying to install it in 22.04 I get this error:

`E: Package 'collectd' has no installation candidate`

[screenshot of errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJmDT.jpg)

Why is this?

Comment: Start by reading this https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask As posted there is noting to use to try and help you.

Comment: You have installed something manually, that has a dependency that can't be found in the repositories.

Comment: I have attempted to edit the question to be more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The collectd package is not currently, as of October 2022, available in the 22.04 repos.

I found this Launchpad Bug about it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/collectd/+bug/1971093